# Почему async/await работает корректно, хотя ему не передаются коллбэки

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise, ecmascript

Пытаюсь разобраться в промисах и `async/await`. Нашёл на хабре этот пример:

```js
async function getAmount2(userId){
    let user =await getUser(userId);
    let amount = await getBankBalance(user);
    alert(amount);
}

getAmount2("1");

function getUser(userId){
    return new Promise((resolve)=>{
        setTimeout(()=>{
            resolve("John");
        }, 10);
    });
}

function getBankBalance(user){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
        setTimeout(()=>{
            if(user=='John'){
                resolve("1,000$");
            }else{
                reject("Unknown user!");
            }
        },10);
    });
}
```

В результате выводится сообщение "1,000$". Но почему? Как я понял из промисов, им надо передавать коллбэки в параметры `resolve` и/или `reject`, которые и будут вызываться в промисе. А здесь никакие функции не передаются, но промисы выполняются, и переменные получают свои значения. Но почему? Ведь в этом примере ни `resolve`, ни `reject` не реализованы

Comment: `resolve` - это и есть колбек, который надо вызвать, что бы промис завершился.

Comment: resolve и reject это и есть коллбэки. Если промис отработал без ошибок, результат выполнения передаётся в resolve, иначе результат ошибки передаётся в reject. По выполнении промиса просто вызывается либо резолв, либо реджект.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обратите внимание на [документацию](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve): resolve, как и reject - это методы, которые вы вызываете и в качестве аргумента передаёте **значение**, с которым промис будет выполнен или не выполнен.
Вы, конечно, можете передать и функцию в качестве значения, но она не будет коллбэком, не будет вызвана, если только при обработке результата промиса вы не вызовете её сами.

Так что да, пример корректный, потому и работает.